# Drop down popup is not showing using marionette.js and jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using marionette.js and jquery mobile  for my application. Following is the code that I have used in template file  for drop down but its not working, I have used "data-native-menu=false" for displaying option in popup

```html
<div id="whatDiv" data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label >Main Category</label><br>     
  <select data-native-menu=false>
    <option value=1> Balance </option>
    <option value=2> 2 </option>
    <option value=3> 3 </option>
    <option value=4> 4  </option>
    <option value=5> 5 </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

i think you want like this , see below jsfiddle links

www.jsfiddle.net/57eJm/